# How to add onClick to button tag in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a button using Javascript but why does the upB.onClick = testUp() not work?

```
<button class="up_btn" onClick="testUp()">Up</button>
```

```
var upB = document.createElement('button');
upB.classList.add("up_btn");
upB.innerText = "Up";
upB.onClick = testUp();
```

Comment: You if you are calling function then it will return function's result, but if you are not calling function by removing `()`, then it's going to run function at click. Example: `upB.onclick = testUp`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#examples

Comment: Because html attributes fix your case mistakes, JavaScript is not that nice. And you are calling your method and assigning what it returns. You are not assigning the method to the event listener.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `upB.setAttribute('onclick','testUp()') ;`

```js
var upB = document.createElement('button');
upB.classList.add("up_btn");
upB.innerText = "Up";
upB.setAttribute('onclick','testUp()') ;
document.body.appendChild(upB);

function testUp(){alert('testUp')}
```

EDIT : following suggestion in comment, please see snippet below with  `addEventListener`.

```js
var upB = document.createElement('button');
upB.classList.add("up_btn");
upB.innerText = "Up";
upB.addEventListener("click", testUp, false);
document.body.appendChild(upB);

function testUp(){alert('testUp')}
```

Comment: And 99.5% of the developers would never use setAttribute for events.

Comment: just a quick and simple answer to his question. Yes there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Yes, use addEventListener

Comment: @epascarello there you go, edited my answer to add the `addEventListener` snippet

Comment: to be fair, I think the first snippet is still valid because it creates the button with the "onclick" attribute, which is what was asked by the question in my opinion.

Comment: What if I want to pass in parameters into the function? Would it still work? I am very new to this.

Comment: Yes you can pass parameters like this `upB.addEventListener("click", testUp(parameter), false);`